# iOS 6.1 - How do I implement imagePickerControllerDidCancel for a non-modal UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios6.1, non-modal

On **iOS 6.1**, I am displaying a **UIImagePickerController** non-modally in one tab of a **UITabBar**.

In my init:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
```

I have implemented:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    return;
}
```

Since I never called:

```
[picker presentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL) completion:^(void)completion];
```

I shouldn't need to call:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

But, when I press the **Cancel** button, the **Cancel** button is grayed out and the **UIImagePickerController** seems to lock up. Some of the controls work, like the image/video switch and the reverse camera button, but the button to take a picture is frozen.

If I go to a different tab and return to the Camera tab, the **UIImagePickerController** is reset and fine again. The only code executed in this case is **viewWillAppear** and **viewDidAppear** which shouldn't have anything relevant to this situation.

On **iOS 7**,nothing locks up when the **Cancel** button is pressed.

Since the **UIImagePickerController** is always displayed in the tab, I don't really have a need for a cancel button so how would I either:

- Hide or disable the **Cancel** button
- Implement **imagePickerControllerDidCancel** so things do not lock up

Comment: Hmmm, think I should look into using an overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implemented a Camera Overlay View and things work fine.**

```
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    UIView *clearView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    clearView.opaque = NO;
    clearView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height-55, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
    toolBar.barStyle =  UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(takePicture)],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                    nil];
    [toolBar setItems:items];

    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [overlayView addSubview:clearView];
    [overlayView addSubview:toolBar];

    [self.picker setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];

    [self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
```

**[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] ... action:@selector(takePicture)],**

```
- (void)takePicture
{
    [self.picker takePicture]; // triggers didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo
}
```

**UIImagePickerControllerDelegate**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if (image != nil)
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
```